# How to center an image within a flex item (cell)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I have a 3x3 flexbox with an icon and title in each item/cell. I am just trying to horizontally center the icon (svg image). I tried `justify-content: center;` but it doesn't seem to work. Can any tell me how to horizontally center an image within a flexbox item (or cell, as I am referring to it as)? Code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="images/cs_icon_01.svg">
        <div class="service-title">Materials Handling, Warehousing &amp; Storage Facility Management</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.cell {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid img {
  width: 45px;
}

.service-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4e4e4e;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 20px 16px 4px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: We call them "elements", not "items" or, worse, "cells" which is reminiscent of tables. Flex'ed elements, and their contents, are standard HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I read on an flexbox article that it was container > items. Possibly just that author's wording. I was just using cells to be clear as to what was being centered in what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give a try to the classic `display`+`margin`:

```
.grid img {
  width: 45px;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;/* horizontal center effect */
}
```

or use text-align:

```
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*justify-content*/ text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What the…! I was certain I already tried that. I guess not – it worked! Thanks.