# Horizontaly center an image in flex display?

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I wan't to center an image in my flex navbar but i can't, i already tried this: [How to center an image within a flex item (cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026081/how-to-center-an-image-within-a-flex-item-cell), but doesn't work.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

nav #this img {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  line-height: 3.2em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.login {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myimage">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50">
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `#myimage {
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update your CSS with few updates. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

nav #this img {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.login {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self: center;
}

.flexItem {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item flexItem">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myimage">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50">
  </div>
  <div class="login flexItem">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what are you doing with this:

```
nav #this img {
 height: 5em;
 width: 5em;
}
```

i think you wanted something like this:

```
nav #myimage img {
 height: 5em;
 width: 5em;
}
```

To center in flexbox, use the justify-content to the primary axis and align-items to the secondary in the flexbox parent element.
in this case you can do it at nav and align the 3 directly children divs at center.

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  align-items: center;
}
```

instead if you want to positionate the image in its parent div, its the same, set display: flex and align items to the parent element (#myimage):

```
#myimage{
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, it is #myimage, thank for yout answer, it is not what i'm looking for, i wan't to horizontaly centor, not verticaly, but ty :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
}

nav #this img {
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  line-height: 3.2em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.login {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self: center;
}
#myimage {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myimage">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50">
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
    <div> Content </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```